# Why sp_rename don't work for CHECK constraint?

Tags: sql-server, rename, check-constraint

To rename the CHECK I use query like this:

```
 EXEC sp_rename 'test_create_table.test_check.check_1', 'check1', 'OBJECT'
```

Query executes without error but the name of constraint not changed.

Some one knows why?

Comment: Where are you checking the name afterwards?

Comment: Yes. In sys.check_constraints - the name of constraint did not change. In the sys.objects too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pay special heed to the warning on the page of [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx):

> If the object to be renamed is a constraint, *object_name* must be in the form *schema.constraint*.

Which I don't think the name you're giving is. So, if this is a constraint on a table called `test_create_table` in the `foobar` schema, what you actually need is:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'foobar.check_1', 'check1', 'OBJECT'
```

I don't know why it doesn't give any form of feedback when you try it the other way, but you'll note that you *don't* receive this message either:

> Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures.

Which is the usual output when `sp_rename` is *successful*.

Comment: Yes, the problem was in the table name in the object definition. Need to use only: schema_name.constraint_name

Answer (score 0):

This should successfully rename your table. I modified your command a bit.

EXEC sp_rename 'test_create_table.test_check', 'check1';

Just verifying what I'm seeing - test_create_table is the name of your schema, test_check is the name of your table, and you are remaing the table to check1?

Also, it looks like you are including an object.  Make sure you have created your obect: CREATE OBJECT YourObjectName
    ON include your table information here.

This link might also help: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx

The example with the object code is at the bottom.

Comment: No, I try to rename the CONSTRAINT with name check_1 of table test_check from schema test_create_table.